# C# GroupBy Two Keys Facing Trouble

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, group-by

In my controller, I want to group my database table records by two columns.

Here is my code thus far:

```
List<tblFAM> tblFAMs = db.tblFAMS.Where(x => x.CDate.Year == year && x.Ftype == 1).ToList();

vmMonthlyReport.FByCounty = tblFAMs.GroupBy(x => new { x.code_County.County, x.CDate.Month})
    .Select(t => new FByCountyProxy()
    {
        CountyName = t.Key.County,
        MonthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(t.Key.Month),
        CountyCount = t.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

This is creating a problem in my view:

[image]

Here is my view code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        @foreach (var month in Model.FByCounty)
        {
            <th>
                @month.MonthName
            </th>
        }
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.FByCounty)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.CountyName</td>
            <td>@item.CountyCount</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR**

```
|          | Jan |  Feb  | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul |
---------------------------------------------------------
New Castle |  x  |   x   |  x  |  x  |  x  |  x  |  x  |
Kent       |  x  |   x   |  x  |  x  |  x  |  x  |  x  |
Sussex     |  x  |   x   |  x  |  x  |  x  |  x  |  x  |
```

What I want is to have the month names displayed across the top only once (no repeats, as what you can see is happening thus far from the picture)... then in the body of the table only have 3 rows.. one for each county.. then a count in each `td` element under the corresponding month.

I am not sure why the month and county are repeating if I'm grouping by those 2 columns? Also, if the `Count` for a specific County is `0`.. I would like that to show as well, instead of just blank.

**UPDATE**

**C# - Controller**

```
List<tblFAM> tblFAMs = db.tblFAMS.Where(x => x.CDate.Year == year && x.Ftype == 1).ToList();

            vmMonthlyReport.FByCounty = tblFAMs.GroupBy(x => x.code_County.County).ToList();
```

**C# - Class**

```
public class vmMonthlyReport
{
    public vmMonthlyReport()
    {
        FByCounty = new List<IGrouping<string, tblFAM>>();();
    }
    public List<IGrouping<string, tblFAM>> FByCounty { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            @for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            {
                <th>
                    @CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(i)
                </th>
            }
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.FByCounty)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Key</td>
                @for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
                {
                    <td>
                        @item.Count(x => x.CDate.Month == i)
                    </td>
                }
                @*<td>
                    @Model.FByCounty.Count(x => x.Key == item.Key)
                </td>*@
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to create the month names just do something like this

```
@foreach (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    <th>
        @CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(i)
    </th>
}
```

That way you should get all the months even if you don't have data for all of them.

Then to populate it you can do the following

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.FByCounty.GroupBy(x => x.CountyName))
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Key</td>
        @for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            <td>@item.Where(x => x.MonthName == CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(i))
                 .Select(x => x.CountyCount)
                 .SingleOrDefault()</td>
        }
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

Though it would be better to select the month number instead of the name to simplify the code.

Comment: This answer is better, deleted mine.

Comment: Do I need to edit my controller code, since I'm now grouping in the view?

Comment: @Grizzly  You could definitely change the model you're using to be something that will work better.  Either group on County first then do a grouping on the month in the select.  Or just make your model have counts for each month, like `JanuaryCount = t.Where(x => x.Month == 1).Count()`.

Comment: Okay, I have it working.  One more thing.. if I wanted an extra column at the end of the table called 'Total', what would I need to do in order to add all of the numbers in each row and have the sum show as the total in the last column?

Comment: @Grizzly `@item.Sum(x => x.CountyCount)` would give you the sum of all the counts for a given county.

Comment: @juharr I've posted an update.  I'm confused.. I changed my model, so that the code looks cleaner.. so as of now, I don't have the property `CountyCount`

Comment: @Grizzly Based on what you have now you'd want `@item.Count()` for the total.